# How can I get the permissions of my Android / iOS application from my WebView in javascript?

Tags: android, ios

I would like to know how I could obtain or read the permissions that the user granted in my application from a webview in javascript.
For example, in my webview I occupy the camera, but if the user denied access to the camera, as I could know from my webview in javascript that the use of the camera is denied and not show the option to the user (because that would truncate my app

PD: Preferably not involving modifications in IOS / ANDROID.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a JavaScript Interface:

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "myApplication");
```

**JavaScriptInterface.java**:

```
public class JavaScriptInterface {
    private WeakReference<Activity> mActivityWeakReference;
    public JavaScriptInterface(Activity activity) {
        this.mActivityWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(activity);
    }
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void requestCameraPermission() {
        if (mActivityWeakReference.get() != null) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermission(mActivityWeakReference.get(), ....);
        }
    }
}
```

And then in your JavaScript code:

```
window.myApplication = function AndroidClass(){};

window.myApplication.requestCameraPermission();
```

More info about implementation [here](https://medium.com/@elye.project/making-android-interacting-with-web-app-921be14f99d8).

Comment: A direct way of javascript could ?, without touching my android application.

Comment: I'm afraid not. Android partnership is essential in this matter. Particular web features are not allowed to approach until the permission is granted by the hosting operating system, in this case Android. Besides Android classes structure and permission granting system is different compared to web, so a joint would be necessary in this participant. This is where `JavaScriptInterface` comes in between.